# pretty print json directly in page from Express

Tags: json, object, express

I'd like to pretty print a large javascript object in my browser window using Express. I've tried res.json() and res.send() with pretty print turned on in express, but it looks like that only works for html and not objects. The response is only the javascript object which is all I need so I'm trying to avoid building an html / jade, capturing the response and using json.stringify(). Is there a way to make the server respond with a nicely formatted object?

Comment: What's the use case?  If you just want it for yourself, there are some [browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en) extensions.

Comment: @Brennan Good call on the browser extensions. I ended up just making an angular page and doing JSON.stringify() to get the nice output I wanted, but hitting the route in Postman does it for me automatically. If you make a response, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out!  I've submitted a short answer with the browser extensions and a link to Postman as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're going for using [browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en) extensions or a program like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) will make it easier for you to develop against.

Answer (score 4):

I see Im really late to the party but... according to the express docs at http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set you should just use `'json spaces'`, which sets the spaces of the `JSON.stringify()` function used by express in `response.json()`

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.set('json spaces', 4)
```

which gives you exactly what you are looking for